# GetIdletime in windows mobile using c#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

**Hi,** 
       I need to get the idle time of the device in one of my windows mobile app. I tried all the way i couldn't get it. could Any one post the code for it..

Thanks  in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To get it to work, you'll need the [GetIdleTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915334.aspx) function from *coredll.dll*.

To access it you can use a P/Invoke command which is [stated here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/GetIdleTime.html):

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
static extern int GetIdleTime ();
```

Also you should note that some devices don't support this functionality and return a MAXDWORD instead (see GetIdleTime() description in block Return Value).

Comment: i used the same but, when i call that method inside my timer control event which is keep on incrementing even though i am not doing any thing.

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood your comment, but GetIdleTime() will increase if you do nothing, hence the name.